# keyPathsForValuesAffecting with NSManagedObject

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

Bonjour,
I would like to translate an objective'c exercise from an Aaron's book to swift but I can't find the solution. The Objective'c code is :

```
@dynamic firstName;
@dynamic lastName;
@dynamic department;

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingFullName
{
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"firstName", @"lastName", nil];
}

- (NSString *)fullName
{
    NSString *first = [self firstName];
    NSString *last = [self lastName];
    if (!first)
        return last;
    if (!last)
        return first;
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", first, last];
}
```

I found a function in the developer documentation but I can't understand how to implement this code.

to be more explicit, this is the Apple doc

> To-one Relationships

To trigger notifications automatically for a to-one relationship you should either override keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey: or implement a suitable method that follows the pattern it defines for registering dependent keys.

For example, the full name of a person is dependent on both the first and last names. A method that returns the full name could be written as follows:

```
- (NSString *)fullName {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName, lastName];
}
```

An application observing the fullName property must be notified when either the firstName or lastName properties change, as they affect the value of the property.

One solution is to override keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey: specifying that the fullName property of a person is dependent on the lastName and firstName properties. Listing 1 shows an example implementation of such a dependency:

Listing 1  Example implementation of keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:(NSString *)key {

    NSSet *keyPaths = [super keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:key];

    if ([key isEqualToString:@"fullName"]) {
        NSArray *affectingKeys = @[@"lastName", @"firstName"];
        keyPaths = [keyPaths setByAddingObjectsFromArray:affectingKeys];
    }
    return keyPaths;
}

class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey(_ key: String) -> NSSet
```

Can somebody tell me how implement this function in swift?

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem!
Just override the func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey(key: String)  with **class** before

Here the code:

```
class Locataires: NSManagedObject {
@NSManaged var firstName: String
@NSManaged var lastName: String
var fullName: NSString {
    get {
 return firstName + lastName
    }
}

override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey(key: String) -> NSSet {
    if key == «fullName « {
        let mesClefs = ["firstName", "lastName"]
        return NSSet(array: mesClefs)
    }
    else {
        return super.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey(key)
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help
Jan

Comment: Note that for Swift 2.x, the signature of the class function must be `override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey(key: String) -> Set<String>`

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 4 solution is:

```
@objc dynamic var firstName: String = ""
@objc dynamic var lastName: String = ""
@objc dynamic var fullName: String {
  return "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
}

@objc class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingFullName() -> Set<String> {
  return Set(["firstName", "lastName"])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for **XCode 9+, and Swift 4.0** (Apple Swift version 4.0.2 (swiftlang-900.0.69.2 clang-900.0.38):

```
@objc public class MyKVOClass : NSObject
{
    // MARK: Properties

    @objc dynamic var myKVOSubclass : KVOSubclass?
    @objc dynamic var myKVOProperty : String?

    @objc dynamic var myComputedKVOProperty : String? {
        guard let mySubclassPropertyValue = self.myKVOSubclass?.mySubclassProperty,
            let myKVOPropertyValue = self.myKVOProperty else { return nil }

        let myComputedKVOPropertyValue = NSString(format:"%@ %@",mySubclassPropertyValue, myKVOPropertyValue)
        return myComputedKVOPropertyValue as String
    }

    // MARK: Initialization

    @objc public required override init() {
        super.init()
    }

  // MARK: KVO

  public override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String>
  {
    if key == "myComputedKVOProperty" {
      return Set(["myKVOSubclass",
      "myKVOSubclass.mySubclassProperty",
      "myKVOProperty"])
    }
    // NOTE : Add more keys with the name of the property if needed...

    return Set([])
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Darkwonder. It works in Swift 4!!!

**Before** - Adding didSet to all dependent properties:

```
class MyViewController: NSViewController {

  // bound to a Value of NSTextField with NumberFormatter
  @objc dynamic var amountOfBetOnRed: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
      updatebetButtonEnabled()
    }
  }

  // same above
  @objc dynamic var amountOfBetOnBlack: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
      updatebetButtonEnabled()
    }
  }

  // bound to a Enabled of NSButton
  @objc dynamic var betButtonEnabled: Bool = false

  func updatebetButtonEnabled() {
    betButtonEnabled = amountOfBetOnRed != 0 || amountOfBetOnBlack != 0
  }

}
```

**After** - Replacing the didSet(s) with a computed property:

```
class MyViewController: NSViewController {

  @objc dynamic var amountOfBetOnRed: Int = 0

  @objc dynamic var amountOfBetOnBlack: Int = 0

  @objc dynamic var betButtonEnabled: Bool {
    get {
      return amountOfBetOnRed != 0 || amountOfBetOnBlack != 0
    }
  }

  override class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String> {
    print("Debug: called for:", key)

    switch key {
    case "betButtonEnabled" :
      return Set(["amountOfBetOnRed", "amountOfBetOnBlack"])
    default :
      return super.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey: key)
    }
  }

}
```

`get { }` can be omitted and just leave `return ...`, but I used `get` here to highlight that it is a computed property.

Confirmed with Xcode 9.0 with a pseudo code like above.

**Added**:

What I have learned so far: The function `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue` is called several times with each property name specified as `@objc dynamic` one by one after returning from init(). This implementation allows us to tell what properties are depended on what properties. Actually, `addObserver` is automatically called on behalf of us behind the scenes. That function is not called for other ordinal properties such as just `var` without `@objc dynamic`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a safer (because of #keyPath), shorter version for Swift 4:

```
override public class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey key: String) -> Set<String> {
    return [
        #keyPath(Track.rTitle): [#keyPath(Track.title)],
        #keyPath(Track.rSource): [#keyPath(Track.album), #keyPath(Track.author)],
        ][key] ?? super.keyPathsForValuesAffectingValue(forKey: key)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to check when the names or department is updated, just use Swift's `dynamic` keyword like so:

```
dynamic var firstName: String
```

You can then follow Apple's documentation on adopting Key-Value observing in Swift by following the [Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html)

Summary:

1. Add the `dynamic` keyword to any property you want to observe.
2. Create a global context variable as per Apple's documentation.
3. Override the `observeValueForKeyPath` method.

Comment: But when you change `firstName`or `lastName`, `fullName` is not notified of these changes, it's why I must implement `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey("fullName")` , no ?

Comment: Well, in that case, you could make use of Swift's property observers. For instance, you can have a didSet and willSet observers for your fullName and it will notify you when the property gets set.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say that `fullName`is a read-only var (just a GET ), only `lastName` and `firstName `change and `fullName` is not notified of these changes.

Comment: You can just check inside that getter method for `fullName`. Or have a variable that gets set when the getter for `fullName` is called.

Comment: I will give you more for understand my problem. I bind `firstName, lastName and fullName (read-only)` To an NSArrayController filled with `Name Entity`, when I update these properties, they update continuously, but fullname doesn’t because it's a read-only property. If I could fill a set with ` keypathsforvaluesaffectingvalueforkey("full Name") { return NSSet(objets: "first Name", "last Name") } ` fullname`will be notifies of these changes and update itself. I tested `dynamic`but nothing happened !